# Difficulty loading Javascript package with Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, npm

I'm pretty new to Javascript and have been trying to avoid it as much as possible, but I need to add a OpenSeadragon viewer to a Flask site. I have the deepzoom image tower created successfully and I thought I was basically done when I realized that I simply could not get around this error. I'm using the sample block of code from the documentation:

```
<div id="openseadragon1" style="width: 955px; height: 693px;"></div>
<script src="/static/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon1",
        prefixUrl: "/openseadragon/images/",
        tileSources: "/repos/analysis/output/img.dzi",
    });

</script>
```

Every time I run this I get nailed with an "Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenSeadragon is not defined"

Further investigation shows that the script source is apparently not being found, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

I'm pretty sure I installed the OSG package properly with npm but I can't be sure. I installed it under the Flask static folder which I believe is correct but I almost never use Javascript or Rlask so I wouldn't know.

I suspect that the source path for the js function might be incorrect but I have tried a bunch of different ones with very little changes in results.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you putting this block of code exactly? In the head section of your index.html page? More than likely, the file is not loaded and parsed before you make the  call to use it.

Comment: @TimConsolazio This is in a file called ai_image.html, which is loaded when a certain route accessed. Is there a way to force the loading and parse?

Comment: Try leaving everything else where it is, but put the script src="/static/...openseadragon.min.js" tag in the head section of your index.html page. That should ensure (not absolutely, but it should do the trick) that the script is fully loaded before the you try to access it.

Comment: @TimConsolazio Granted I might be doing this incorrectly cause I don't usually do front-end, but I believe I put the tag in my head section and I'm now getting the following error:  net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: I just realized that my .css file isn't even loading so I'll likely repost the question reframed around none of my static files showing up

Comment: Yeah it sounds like your whole front end setup is wonky. 404 means "not found". So the path to the file relative to your index page is undoubtedly wrong (Flask configures paths to assets in a specific way). Also, if you view the source of the openseadragon page itself, you see the script load is in the head tag (which is interesting because that's not how their docs show the basic usage).

Comment: Oh btw regarding your static files, you need to look in the Flask documentation:  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files